# valiadte textbox in dojo

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo

I am trying to validate a textbox:

I have 2 textboxes.  If value of 1st textbox or 2nd textbox is valid then form will be submitted successfully, and if both textboxes are empty then it will show the error .

Here is my code:

```
<script>
           dojo.require("dojo.parser"); 
           dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"); 
           dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
            dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
                </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" action="" id="myForm" data-dojo-id="myForm" method="post">
                <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onReset">
                    return confirm('Press OK to reset values');
                </script>
                <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onSubmit">
                    if(this.validate()){
                    return true;
                    }else{
                    if((dijit.byId('a').value==null && dijit.byId('b').value!=null) ){

                    alert('Valid data');
                    return true;
                    }
                    alert('Form contains invalid data.  Please correct first');
                    return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                </script>

                <input type="text" name="a" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true" id="a"/>
        <input type="text" name="b" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true" id="b"/>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

It's not working, any advice on why?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the text boxes will not be null, it would be initialized as empty string, if not provided any value in declaration.
For you case, try changing the condition as follow:

```
if((!dijit.byId('a').value && !dijit.byId('b').value)){
    this.validate();
    alert('Not Valid Form!');
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```